# How do I make everything appear on one screen in Mavericks

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mac

When I open illustrator and move it to my secondary monitor in Mavericks and try and open anything... for example a new document, it will appear in my laptop screen as opposed to my second monitor. Is there any way for me to make windows open in the screen that is actively running the program or do I just have to drag one by one?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Graphic Design. This question isn't about Graphic Design as specified in our Help Center FAQ: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and so will likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you set your secondary screen as the main screen, photoshop, illustrator and indesign will open their dialogs in it.

You can do that by going to System preferences > displays. and drag the white top menu to the secondary screen.

[image]

---

---

In Mavericks you can set applications to open in a specific screen, but I haven't found that to work reliably with specifically indesign and illustrator. It does work with photoshop...

[image]